# Clicking the javascript related button opens the relevant menu

Tags: javascript

How do I get the corresponding div element when the corresponding button is pressed

```html
<div id="1" class="box"></div>
<div id="2" class="box"></div>
<div id="3" class="box"></div>
<button id="1" onClick="menu(this.id)">B1</button>
<button id="2" onClick="menu(this.id)">B2</button>
<button id="3" onClick="menu(this.id)">B3</button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function menu(clicked_id)
  {     
    var box = document.getElementsBy??????('??????');
  if(clicked_id == box){Some code brrr....}
 } 
</script>
```

any help document would be very helpful;)

Comment: IDs have to be unique. Don't use the same ID for the button and the DIV.

Comment: So, how should I proceed after that? How do I relate the two elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the same ID for the button and the DIV.

You can use a `data-XXX` attribute on the button to identify the related DIV.

```js
function menu(box_id) {
  document.querySelectorAll(".box").forEach(box => box.classList.remove("active"));
  var box = document.getElementById(box_id);
  box.classList.add("active");
}
```

```css
.box.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="1" class="box">DIV 1</div>
<div id="2" class="box">DIV 2</div>
<div id="3" class="box">DIV 3</div>
<button data-box="1" onClick="menu(this.dataset.box)">B1</button>
<button data-box="2" onClick="menu(this.dataset.box)">B2</button>
<button data-box="3" onClick="menu(this.dataset.box)">B3</button>
```